# Android Studio Library is not used

Tags: android, android-maps

Today I preinstall my Windows 7 to Windows 8.

After that I install Android Studio 0.4.2 and open my old project, he use google maps apiV2.
But when I compile and run my app the google maps has gray screen.After that I go to File > Project Structure and below in that window I have that 4 errors.

And for 4 - 5 hours I'am trying to solve how to use the librarys again like before with my old windows.

[image]

Comment: I'am not sure but you get a gray screen because your MAPS API is not valid. As you made a new instalation of Android Studio in a new OS, the debugKey was changed

Comment: Yes and I was thinking about that, but I tried with new api key from the new "debug.keystore" and still I have the same problem.

Comment: The errors you're seeing in Project Structure are bogus and we need to remove them; https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60958 tracks the progress of that.